# Do I need different RJ45 plugs?

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable, rj-45, cat5e

I bought this [ICIDU UTP CAT5E Pullbox Solid Wire Straight 100m Network Cable](http://www.amazon.co.uk/ICIDU-CAT5E-Pullbox-Straight-Network/dp/B003V5IRYW) and these [100pcs UTP Male RJ45 Connectors (CAT5/6) Ready](http://www.scan.co.uk/products/100pcs-utp-male-connectors) plugs.

I've tried time and time again repeated watching and reading tutorials double-triple-quadruple checking the ordering of my wires.

However, every single attempt the cable never works

Is this because the plugs  I have are best suited to stranded cable and not solid?

Should I buy some new plugs as at this point it's the only thing I can think that's letting me down.

I've even tried splicing other ends of plugs onto this cable and they've worked fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just buy pre-made cables?

Comment: When I first started making up my own cables I had about a 20% hit-rate. It just gets better over time. [so far, comment 1 wins my vote, unless you have real patience]

Comment: I've heard this from a lot of people but I don't understand what finesse there is to be had? You strip the outer casing. Separate and straighten your wires. Align them in the correct order. Cut the ends of all the individual wires so they're all flush. Push the wires into the plugs firmly. Finally crimping the plug pressing the pins into the individual wires and securing the wire.

Comment: I click the link for the connecttors and saw this in product reviews: "Not the best quality
Not pure copper
Had issues with nearly every one"

Comment: I guess I'll buy some new connectors and cross my fingers then. :P

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, yes.  It's impossible to tell from the link you provided, but these are likely the more common type of RJ45 plugs that have straight blades designed for going *through* stranded cable.

[image]

There is a good reason why plugs for solid aren't common: it's bad practice.  If you're making patch cables, the cable should have stranded wire to allow it to move and flex freely.  If you're running structured cabling (e.g. in wall/ceiling, patch panel/rack, stapled along a baseboard/wall/etc) the ends should be terminated with jack of some kind, not a plug.